# Como faço reset no setInterval() de uma funçao?

Tags: javascript

Ola, eu estou a ter problemas em fazer reset no setInterval() em 2 funções, elas têm que ser re-usadas nos Ids afetados

Aqui está o codigo JS:

```
//Fuction Fade out
function fadeOut(elem, speed) {
    if (!elem.style.opacity) {
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (elem.style.opacity >= 1) {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (elem.style.opacity >= 0) {
                elem.style.opacity = parseFloat(elem.style.opacity) - 0.03;
            }
        }, speed / 50);
        if (elem.style.opacity >= 1) {
            clearInterval(0);
        }
    }
}


//Função fade in
function fadeIn(elem, speed) {

    if (!elem.style.opacity) {
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
    }

    /*var timerId=*/
    if (elem.style.opacity <= 0) {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (elem.style.opacity <= 1) {
                elem.style.opacity = parseFloat(elem.style.opacity) + 0.03;
            }
        }, speed / 50);
    }
    /*if(elem.style.opacity >="1"){
        clearInterval(timerId);
        return;} */
}
```

PS: Eu tentei resolver o meu problema com um `while`, mas não resultou, quando implemento o terceiro "`if`" na função fade out, a opacidade desce, mas em vez de ir até `0`, vai ate `0,99`, como resolvo o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de ter alguma maneira de saber se o elemento está a ser animado e gerir isso. O próprio contador (setInterval) retorna um ponteiro de si próprio para poder ser cancelado, usando isso podes pará-lo.

Uma sugestão seria usar uma função para animações assim:

```
function tween(el, to, speed) {
    if (el._isAnimating) clearInterval(el._tween);
    var opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(el).opacity);
    if (to == opacity) return; // não precisa animar
    else el._isAnimating = true;
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    var incr = 0.03 * (to > opacity ? 1 : -1);

    el._tween = setInterval(function() {
        var next = Number(el.style.opacity) + incr;
        if ((incr > 0 && next > to) || (incr < 0 && next < to)) {
            el.style.opacity = to;
            return clearInterval(el._tween);
        }
        el.style.opacity = next;
    }, speed / 50);

}

//Fuction Fade out
function fadeOut(elem, speed) {
    tween(elem, 0, speed);
}

//Função fade in
function fadeIn(elem, speed) {
    tween(elem, 1, speed);
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/dk7y280c/

Com este código podes clicar muitas vezes em fadeIn e fadeOut que ele interrompe a animação em curso e inicia a nova ordem. Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/dk7y280c/1/

Comment: `return function() {
        window[fn](h, 1000);
    }` pode explicar-me esta linha sff

Comment: @Miguel Essa linha é só para fazer o exemplo funcionar. Como defeni as funçoes no escopo global elas estão acessíveis via `window`. Sendo que dei o mesmo `id` aos botões como os nomes das funções, fiz assim para fazer com que o clique no botão invoque a função respectiva.

Comment: Obrigao @Sergio

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: @DiogoMiranda de nada. Se resolveu o teu problema podes marcar a resposta como aceite.