# Uma transição afeta a opacidade da outra redefinindo 'globalAlpha' no canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Eu estou fazendo um jogo e atualmente estou construindo uma tela onde teria uma transição de opacidade (*fade in*) e, após ser finalizada, iniciaria outra transição de opacidade.

O problema é quando a primeira transição termina e a outra começa, já que a primeira transição acompanha a opacidade da outra. E eu estou redefinindo o `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.globalAlpha` para desenhar com transparência diferente.

Exemplo:

```
// Isso é memorizado em um bloco anterior
var alpha0 = 0, // A opacidade da primeira transição
    alpha1 = 0; // A opacidade da outra

// ===========================================

// Enquanto o jogo executa, esse bloco executa
context.globalAlpha = alpha0;
// ...

context.globalAlpha = alpha1;
// ...

if(alpha0 < 1)
    alpha0 += 0.1;

;else if(alpha1 < 1)
    alpha1 += 0.1;
```

Pois quando eu desenho qualquer coisa depois de definir a opacidade atual da primeira transição e a segunda transição começa eu enxergo o desenho ter a opacidade atual da segunda transição.

Comment: Dá uma olhada a esta função _tween_ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/131063/129. Acho que seria melhor implementar algo parecido para não misturar opacidades?

Comment: @Sergio É ótimo como solução, porém não há maneira de definir opacidade para um objeto, pois o canvas não reconhece (apesar de que eu não uso elementos HTML para fazer o jogo, só o elemento do canvas). Uma alternativa é pegar todos os pixels da imagem/canvas e mudar o valor 'alpha' (opacidade) de cada um através do JS, porém isso é desnecessário e pesado.

Comment: Se fizesses o jogo em SVG talvez fosse mais fácil. Podes criar um jsFiddle simples mas que mostre o problema que estás a ter para podermos testar?

Comment: @Sergio Hospedei no meu site já que ele carrega uns aúdios porque estou testando... http://handoncloud.com/archerOnline/frame.html, você precisa ir na source `Archer.js` (view-source:http://handoncloud.com/archerOnline/data/Archer.js) e ir subindo um pouco até achar uma função chamada `MainMenu`, então vê um tal de `EnterFrame` no bloco dessa função. Embora tem que esperar o jogo carregar pela primeira vez para ver o problema na próxima tela.